# How to filter strings by a limit of how many times each character can occur?

Tags: python

I am trying to code a function that filters a list of strings by a specific limit of how many occurrences of each character are allowed.

For example, here are my inputs:

```
foo = ['BAR', 'BAAR', 'RABA', 'AAARB', ...]
characters = ['B', 'A', 'A', 'R']
```

The output should be:

```
['BAR', 'BAAR', 'RABA']
```

The value AAARB is excluded because it has 3 A's. The value BAR is included because it's fine for it to use fewer than the maximum number of character occurrences.

The process should be efficient because my input list of strings has about 7,300 items and my list of allowed characters always has 12 characters.

Comment: Why is 'BAR" acceptable? Would 'BA' or just 'B' be acceptable too? What about the empty string, if it occurred in the list?

Comment: @DanielPryden yes they would be acceptable. its only about making sure that the given characters (['B', 'A', 'A', 'R']) are not used more than they appear in their list. In AAARB's case the A ist used 3 times but there are only 2 A's in the list so every result MUST HAVE 2 A's, 1 A or 0 A's.
also there will be no empty string,  I'm checking that before.
I am very sorry for my bad english.
thank you for your reply

Comment: For what it's worth, 7,300 strings that are each 12 characters long is only 85 kilobytes of data -- that's actually quite small by modern standards. Any modern system can handle that much data so quickly that it doesn't matter how efficient your implementation is -- it will be faster than you can notice regardless.

Comment: As I said I am new to Python. Actually I thought my program would be inefficient bc it starts with a list of 189065 words and uses them to find a word that i only know length and characters of (but i also know more characters so i dont know which are the right ones)

Maybe you know the android game "4 Pics 1 Word".. I am trying to make a bot for it xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily by comparing the histograms of the allowed characters and the characters in each string. For example:

```
import collections

def find_subsets_of(strings, allowed_chars):
    allowed = collections.Counter(allowed_chars)
    for string in strings:
        counts = collections.Counter(string)
        if all(counts[ch] <= allowed[ch] for ch in counts):
            yield string

result = list(find_subsets_of(foo, characters))
```